# How do I write a list to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to write a list with elements with words from different languages ​​and with numbers to a file?

```
s = ['привет', 'hi', 235, 235, 45]

with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(s)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

Comment: Since you are writing to a `.txt` file, are you sure you want binary output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. For the next time, please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code (done it for you here).

Comment: You never clarified the expected output. Specifically, do you want each entry on a separate line or just all on one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `'wb'` to open the file causes you to write in binary mode. I'm not sure if this is what you want, since you are writing to a `.txt` file.

If you are sure you want to write in binary mode, I would suggest you use `.bin` or `.dat` as the file extension for your file.

If you are sure you want to write the output as binary, here is one way to do so (I make several assumptions here, because you don't give details in your question):

```py
import sys

s = ['привет', 'hi', 235, 235, 45]

# Create an empty bytearray
byte_array = bytearray()

# For each item in the list s, convert it to a bytearray, and append it to the
# output bytearray
for item in s:
    if isinstance(item, str):
        byte_array.extend(bytearray(item, 'utf-8'))
    elif isinstance(item, int):
        # Assumption: all ints in the list can be represented with only 2 bytes
        # Assumption: we want to output with the system's byte order
        byte_array.extend(item.to_bytes(2, sys.byteorder, signed=True))

# Here I use the .bin extension, because it is a binary file
with open('test.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(byte_array)
```

If you instead do not want to write as binary, but want to write as text, see [Spiros Gkogkas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66726759/8593689).

Comment: I need to run through the entire local disk, and write the name of all the files to a file, for example .txt

Comment: including the file directory, for example: ['C:\\Programm\user\blalbalba.txt']

Comment: @mathaslolp Welcome to Stack Overflow. These details belong in your question, and not in the comments on an individual answer. *However*, at this point it sounds like what you want is entirely different from what you asked, in which case you should ask a new question with a description of what you want (i.e.,  I believe you want to know how to run through the entire local disk in python, and write the output from running through the entire local disk to a file).

Answer (score 1):

Well since you are opening a **.txt** file and you mentioned different languages, I will assume that you want to write to a **.txt** file some values with different encoding.

(*If that's not the case and you want to write binary, you can check the answers above*)

You should specify the encoding for the file depending on the values you have.

```
s = ['привет', 'hi', 235, 235, 45]

with open("filename.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(str(val) for val in s))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(', '.join([str(item) for item in s]))
```

It writes every item in a list (first changing every item to a string of course) separated by a comma.

Comment: Note that if you want to use a different delimiter, replace `', '` with the desired delimiter. For example, if you want each item on its own line, use `'\n'` instead of `', '`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe convert (parse) to json string
Like this:

```py
import json

dataList = ["po", "op", "oo"]
dataJson = json.dumps(dataList)
# Then your code
# with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f: f.write(dataJson)
```